# Get elements of a permutation

Tags: numpy

I have an 1D-array whose elements are a permutation of `0:N`, and I need to take the first K elements of this permutation

For example, in the case the permutation is

```
0    [[9]
1     [0]
2     [1]
3     [2]
4     [3]
5     [4]
6     [5]
7     [6]
8     [7]
9     [8]]
```

The first 3 elements are 9 , 8 , 7

The code is

```
    n = start
    r = zeros (nodeCount, dtype = int)
    i = 0
    while (self.nodes[n][direction] != stop):
        r[i] = n
        n = self.nodes[n][direction]
        i+=1
```

I need a **faster way** to extract the elements from permutation.

Answer (score 2):

This works, but I don't think it is going to be especially fast:

```
>>> a
array([9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
>>> n = 3
>>> b = np.empty((n,), dtype=a.dtype)
>>> b[0] = a[0]
>>> for k in xrange(1, n):
...     b[k] = a[b[k-1]]
...
>>> b
array([9, 8, 7])
```

Comment: The only thing I am interested about is the ``speed``. My question could be reformulated so: is there a numpy function that does what I want internally in C code, so without using outside loops ?

Comment: I don't think so. The fact that your next item is based on the value of the previous one makes it inherently recursive. With numpy, you can sometimes skip the recursion, e.g. using a ufunc's [`accumulate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.accumulate.html) method. But `np.take` isn't a ufunc, and I really don't see how else to go about it.

Comment: My rec. does not always loop from 1 to n-1, because the stopping cond may be accomp. before. Otoh, the timeit does not report any kind of real improvement -- in 5 hours if exec., it lows a few sec. My code runs 4-5h until it finds a sol. I need a real speedup... Believe what I say -- not really useful . The problem there is that the cycle can have about 30 000 elements, and the cache is not so great. I really need a complete C function from numpy to do it optimally. What do you say about this : http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html#iterator-allocated-output-arrays ?

Answer (score 0):

Is [`numpy.roll`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) what you're after?

```
>>> a = np.arange(10)
>>> b = np.roll(a,1)
>>> b
array([9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
>>> np.roll(b[::-1],1)[:3]
array([9, 8, 7])
```

That last line of code is pretty cryptic, but `b[::-1]` reverses the array, [`np.roll`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) shifts it, and the `[:3]` only takes the first three elements.

Comment: no :) . In this example displayed there the permutation was the identity permutation. 9 0 1 2 3 ... 8. For other permutation it does not work. I need a code with the same logic as my code, but to work faster, and to work for every permutation.